# Compiling triangle intersection code?

Tags: c++, c, collision-detection, raytracing

My Google-fu has only turned up one result that returns the point of intersection between a ray and a triangle:
http://geomalgorithms.com/a06-_intersect-2.html

And I am having absolutely no luck compiling it. I have done this for the points/vectors:

```
typedef struct {
    float x, y, z;
} Vector;
typedef struct {
    float x, y, z;
} Point;
typedef struct {
    Vector P0, P1;
} Ray;
typedef struct {
    Point V0, V1, V2;
} Triangle;
```

And then it throws errors about this code:

```
u = T.V1 - T.V0;
v = T.V2 - T.V0;
n = u * v;
```

"No match for operator - (operand types are Point and Point)"

So then I rewrote all of the code to be like this:

```
u.x=T.V1.x-T.V0.x;
u.y=T.V1.y-T.V0.y;
u.z=T.V1.z-T.V0.z;
v.x=T.V2.x-T.V0.x;
v.y=T.V2.y-T.V0.y;
v.z=T.V2.z-T.V0.z;
n.x=u.x*v.x;
n.y=u.y*v.y;
n.z=u.z*v.z;
```

But it still says the ray { 3, 1, -3 } { 3, -1, -3 } is not inside the triangle { -10, 0, -10 } { 10, 0, 10 } { 10, 0, -10 }. I checked this in Blender, though, and the ray indeed intersects the triangle.

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing incorrectly, or link to another page with a function that will return the exact point where a line segment intersects a triangle? I would rather do this in C than have to link some vector library. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: You need to define your arithmetic operators for example `operator+`, `operator-`, etc.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: `T` is obviously a `Triangle`.

Comment: @TonyK I don't see how it is _obvious_ to you. I have seen thousands of mistakes caused by this _obvious_ belief. And yes, that "hehe" part in my comment __is__ a typo, it should read `here`.

Comment: just for curiosity: Aren't there 2 intersection points?

Comment: @tobi303: This is in three dimensions.

Comment: @TonyK Oh i see. Still it might be required to take care of the special case, when the ray and triangle are lying in the same plane.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
n = u * v;
```

This has to be interpreted as the vector product **n** = **u** x **v**, not component-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the author of the page did not intend to publish valid out-of-the-box C++ there, as hinted by the quotes he used to write the name of the language. To turn that pseudocode into compilable code, you would need to implement a few operators yourself, such as the cross product of two 3D vectors (this is trivial, by the way).

> *Assume that classes are already given for the objects:*
>   ...